morphisms between the sheaves restricted to open subset

Let $\mathscr F,\mathscr G$ be both sheaves on $X$ and $\varphi$ be morphisms between sheaves $\mathscr F,\mathscr G$. Let $U\subset X$ be an open subset( maybe we do not even need that $U$ is open in $X$ if we use the inverse image construction ). Then we can define sheaves on $U$, namely $\mathscr F|_{U},\mathscr G|_U$ on $U$. Then does $\varphi$ also induces a morphism between $\varphi|_{U}:\mathscr F|_{U}\rightarrow \mathscr G|_U$? Is there any communitivity which has to satisfy?

It might be a easy question but I do not know the answer. Any help is appreciated.

In the case that $U$ is open, you can see this quite directly. Given $V$ an open set of $U$, it is also an open set of $X$ since it can be written as $V = V'\cap U$ where $V'$ is an open in $X$. By definition, $\mathscr{F}|_U(V) = \mathscr{F}(V)$ and so the morphism of sheaves $\varphi_U$ is given over $V$ by $\varphi_U(V) = \varphi(V): \mathscr{F}(V)\to \mathscr{G}(V)$. The required compatibility with restrictions for $\varphi_U$ follows from the corresponding property of $\varphi$.
In general, we can use functoriality of the inverse image construction. That is, if $f:U \to X$ is a continuous map of topological spaces, then $f^{-1}:\mathrm{Sh}(X)\to \mathrm{Sh}(U)$ is a functor from the category of Abelian sheaves on $X$ to the category of Abelian sheaves on $U$. In particular, given $\varphi:\mathscr{F}\to \mathscr{G}$ in $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$, there is an induced morphism $f^{-1}(\varphi): f^{-1}\mathscr{F}\to f^{-1}\mathscr{G}$.

Thanks for your help. In the second paragraph, in order to verify $f^{-1}$ is a functor we can say $f^{-1}(\varphi)$ is a functor because it is induced by universal property of colimits and hence $\mathscr F\rightarrow f^{-1}\mathscr F\rightarrow f^{-1}\mathscr G=\mathscr F\rightarrow \mathscr G\rightarrow f^{-1}\mathscr G$. Did I understand this correctly?

I don't exactly understand the sequence of maps you wrote down, but yes it should follow from the universal property.

Thanks. What I mean by the sequence of maps is that we want to verify $f^{-1}(\varphi)(f^{-1}\mathscr F)=f^{-1}(\varphi(\mathscr F))$ which is needed in order to show $f^{-1}$ is a functor.
